# Green underlines when writing code

Tags: sql, intellisense, underline

There is a green underline similar to the red error underline that IntelliSense has.  However, the green one appears to only point out tables, and SELECT columns.

Nothing is wrong with them.  How do I shut this off?

Comment: Ok a few things - What IDE are you using? What steps have you tried? I.e have you even Googled this?

Comment: As stated in the answer - the green lines are warnings.  If you're using Visual Studio, most warning are configurable... but if you haven't changed anything, you might want to (at least) think about what they are trying to tell you.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the meaning of the lines and other colors/highlights in Tools>>Options>>Fonts and Colors:

[image]

Green squiggly lines are "Warnings". There seems to be mixed results in trying to suppress these or turn them off though.

Comment: despite the mixed results, could you note ways to surpress?  Apparently I make a habit of unqualified column names in SSMS